# A word to discribe un/equally weighted options

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Say for example you have colours to choose from A: red B: yellow C: orange which really doesn't matter, i.e. they play no important roles in your decision, not gaining or losing over one another or they are of equal weights. That I want to call them "*options*".

Now if you are given some other things to choose from, e.g. A: New car B: Travel package C: $30000 which obviously are not of equal weight and choosing between them involve calculating gain/loss, etc. What would you call them? Do you simply call them "*choices*"?

Comment: Does a dog have the Buddha nature? Much of the field of economics discusses choices and a very serious (and currently hot) branch of mathematics is about equatable processes for choosing, voting, and selecting. Despite the relatively high-precision in mathematics, I have never seen a distinction in any field between "option" and "choice" that connoted triviality, a hierarchy, a weighting system, or anything similar. If there are two words that describe the states you are looking for, I do not believe those words are choice and option.

Comment: @HunterHogan Ok I get you. What if I throw in another word 'selection'? Do you think they differ in anyway?

Comment: In my experience, no. There are likely _some_ differences between choice, option, and selection, but I have not seen any terms that differ in the manner you seek. An adjective, such as @bagheera's "trivial", would likely achieve your goal. For adjectives, you can find a rich lexicon in economics, such as "price equilibrium" to describe something similar to your "options"; math has the "fair cake-cutting" problem--analogous to your "choices." Just because I don't know of words that describe what you are looking for, that does not mean you won't find them if you read about those two ideas. GL!

Comment: Would you *opt for an option* (rooted in desire), *choose a choice* (rooted in taste), or *select a selection* (rooted in gathering)? Selecting one of the three words does **not** depend on the value of the options you choose from. Choosing one of the three words does **not** depend on the value of the options you select from. Opting for one of the three words does **not** depend on the value of the choices you select from.

Answer (score 1):

*alternatives*: of two things, propositions, or courses or more mutually exclusive so that if one is chosen the others must be rejected.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alternative

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the word, consider using '***trivial choices***' for the first set and simply 'choices' for the second set.

Comment: So do you think "options" and "choices" mean different things?

Comment: A 'choice' carries more of the connotation of 'personal preference'.

Comment: @user1589188 they are synonymous in many contexts but I think 'trivial choice' is common usage compared to 'trivial option'.

Answer (score 0):

An *option* is something that is presented to you.  A *choice* is something you make.  So your colours are options and your unequally tempting rewards are choices.